# MUI Autocomplete with redux

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm trying to build a search bar with autocomplete', where you can type a city name, choose the city from the list (using autocomplete).
and when selecting the city I want to update the state with the selected city.

here is the code:

```
const SearchBox = (props) => {

  const handleChange=(event)=>{
    props.locationAutocomplete(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    props.currentWeather(event.target.value.key)
    
  }

  return (
    <form onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Autocomplete
          id='location-search-bar'
          options={props.weather.autoCompleteLocations}
          getOptionLabel={(city) =>
            `${city.LocalizedName} , ${city.Country.LocalizedName}`
          }
          onChange={handleChange}
          fullWidth
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label='Location'
              variant='outlined'
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          )}
        />
        <button>search</button>
    </form >
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = state=>({
  weather:state.weather
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{locationAutocomplete,currentWeather,fiveDaysWeather})(SearchBox)
```

the autocomplete is working and when I type a city name it offers my relevant cities,
but the props.currentWeather is never being dispatched.

where is my mistake?

Comment: In the `handleSubmit` what's the value of `event.target.value.key` ?

Comment: its "undefined"

Comment: Ok so I think you should bebug this first...